# Angular6 http.get extract id from call to use in another

Tags: angular, rest, api, typescript

I want to make a call to my REST check for the ServiceProvider ID then use that ID in another call.
I have a method called *GetServiceProviderId()* this will call the API and get the following Json Result: {
    "mitId": 18,
    "ServiceProviderId": "2"
}

Now I want to take the 2 and place it in my other call to fill my list with  *GetInstallation()*

Here is my current code:

```
  GetServiceProviderId() {
    return this.http.get<Info>(this.rooturl + 'info', { headers: this.reqHeader }).subscribe(res => {
      res.ServiceProviderId
    })
  }
```

and this is where I want to use the 2:

```
  GetInstallation() {
    return this.http.get<Installation[]>(this.serviceurl +
      "2"
      , { headers: this.reqHeader })
  }
```

if I replace "2" with this.GetServiceProviderId() I get the following error: GET localhost:50159/installation/?serviceproviderid=**[object%20Object]** 400 (Bad Request)

thanks for reading

Comment: did you log the error in server?

Comment: If I use postman with the correct call localhost:50159/installation/?serviceproviderid= **2** everything works as it should I just somehow need to extract the "2" from the first call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flatMap.  It will call GetServiceProviderId() first, when that resolves it will call your next observable (http get).  When you are using observables everything is lazy, which means you aren't dealing with concrete values. Code isn't executed until you call .subscribe().  It's a weird concept at first and honestly takes time and practice to get your brain wrapped around it.

http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html

```
 GetServiceProvider() : Observable<Info> {
    return this.http.get<Info>(this.rooturl + 'info', { headers: this.reqHeader });
  }

GetInstallation() : Observable<Installation[]> {
    return this.GetServiceProvider().pipe(
        flatMap(info => {
            // ^^ this info object is the result of GetServiceProviderId()
            return this.http.get<Installation[]>(this.serviceurl +
            info.serviceProviderId
          , { headers: this.reqHeader })
        })
);
```

Edit:
I just realized your GetServiceProviderId() function is calling http.get and then subscribing.  I would refactor this and remove the .subscribe() from this method.  Leave it up to the consumer to pull the id out of the info object.

Edit: Additionally, if you have control over the API consider squishing this into one call.  In this case you have to make 2 round trips from your browser to your API.  Even if that means calling a different WebAPI from your server, because more than likely this will be faster.  You never know how slow your users connection will be, so to them these two calls may take 5 seconds to run but for you it may take 250ms.  However, if you retrieve the ServiceProviderId using Server to Server the call may only take them 2 seconds total since they are making one less web request.